# Installing dependency produces: ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree

Tags: node.js, reactjs, angular, react-native, npm

When I try to install a dependency I get the following error. How can I fix this?

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: react-component-depot@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.1.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.8.0" from react-rating-tooltip@1.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react-rating-tooltip
npm ERR!   react-rating-tooltip@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\Swapnil\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Swapnil\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-04-28T10_10_48_716Z-debug-0.log
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a dependency issue, you can ignore it and install npm packages by adding command `--force` or `--legacy-peer-deps`

```
npm install react-rating-tooltip --force
```